# Understanding the order of local variable(s) on the stack frame

Tags: gcc, stack-frame

The C standard doesn't specify the layout of variables on the stack but I want to understand how local variables are arranged by the `gcc` compiler. A simple example is given below

```
void fun(int a, int b, int c, int d, char *pass) {

    int flag = 0x7a69;
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, pass);               
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fun(1, 2, 3, 4, argv[1]);
}
```

No matter what the order of `buffer` & `flag` , the `flag` always comes before the `buffer`.

```
(gdb) p &buffer
$1 = (char (*)[10]) 0xffffcff2

(gdb) p &flag
$2 = (int *) 0xffffcfec
```

I compile the program as:

`gcc -g -m32 test.c`

I tried to reorder the declaration of `buffer` and `flag` in order to see their arrangement on the stack frame but the order was always the same.

1. By looking at the source code, can i guess the order of locals on stack-frame by the `gcc`?
2. On what criteria `gcc` order the locals and why?

Comment: "I want to understand how local variables are arranged by the gcc compiler" Why would you ever want to?

Comment: GCC makes no promises about any of this. It doesn't even promise to put local variables on the stack at all.